Magento 2 How to stop JS script in certain user agents
We are using magento 2.4.7-p3
I have a js script inserted in

admin > content > Configuration > MyStoreView > Html Head > Scripts
and Style Sheets

script is from external adress and it runs in every page before head closing tag.
But we don't want this script to run when bots like Google or Bing crawling the site.
Is that possible please and how?

To load a third-party JavaScript file only if the visitor is not a bot, you can use the following approach -
// List of bot user-agent substrings
const botUserAgents = [
    'Googlebot',
    'Bingbot',
    'Slurp',    // Yahoo
    'DuckDuckBot',
    'Baiduspider',
    'YandexBot',
    'Sogou',
    'Exabot',
    'facebot',  // Facebook
    'ia_archiver'
];

// Function to check if the user-agent matches a bot
function isBot() {
    const userAgent = navigator.userAgent;
    return botUserAgents.some(bot => userAgent.includes(bot));
}

// Load third-party script if not a bot
if (!isBot()) {
    const dyscript = document.createElement('script');
    dyscript.src = 'https://example.com/thirdparty.js'; 
    dyscript.async = true; 
    document.head.appendChild(dyscript);

    console.log('Third-party script added because this is not a bot.');
} else {
    console.log('Third-party script not added because this is a bot.');
}


